# Options for MACRO 1:1 with Built in Motor

Tags: macro, lens-recommendation, macro-lenses, nikon-d5000

I have a D5000 that does not have a built in motor. I am looking for a Macro 1:1 with auto focus as I am just starting in macro and feel that loosing auto focus make the lens less useful.

I am looking for what options are available.

Research so far:

- I think that there are are No Sigma macro lenses that would work?
- The Tamron SP 90mm F/2.8 Di has new version (A272NII) that says should work but cannot find it for sale any where.
- It is unclear what Nikkor Macro lens have a built in motor and would work?
- All lenses are designed full frame but will work the the APS-C

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Tamron A272NII is the older 90mm f/2.8 Di Macro. It's still available on many big sites (at least in the US). The Tamron SP 90mm f/2.8 Di Macro 1:1 VC USD (F017) is their new 90mm macro. I can also find it for Nikon mount on lots of US online retailers (B&H, Adorama), as well as as Amazon.co.uk, Camera World. Jessop's and Calumet both show it as out of stock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nikon's macro lens lineup](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/article/gnhy8b3m/macro-lenses.html) lists the following non-DX (that is, full frame), 1:1 lenses with built-in motor (AF-S):

- [AF-S Micro-NIKKOR 60mm f/2.8G ED](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2177/AF-S-Micro-NIKKOR-60mm-f%252F2.8G-ED.html)
- [AF-S VR Micro-NIKKOR 105mm f/2.8G IF-ED](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2160/AF-S-VR-Micro-NIKKOR-105mm-f%252F2.8G-IF-ED.html)

The following 1:1 AF-S macro lenses are DX designated (that is, designed for APS-C bodies):

- [AF-S DX Micro-NIKKOR 40mm f/2.8G](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2200/AF-S-DX-Micro-NIKKOR-40mm-f%252F2.8G.html#tab-ProductDetail.ProductTabs.Overview)
- [AF-S DX Micro-NIKKOR 85mm f/3.5G ED VR](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2190/AF-S-DX-Micro-NIKKOR-85mm-f%252F3.5G-ED-VR.html)

---

[Tamron's 1:1 macro lens lineup](http://www.tamron-usa.com/lenses/prod/macro.php) shows following Di (full frame) lenses with 1:1, built-in motor:

- [SP 90mm F/2.8 MACRO VC (Model F017)](http://www.tamron-usa.com/F017special/index.html) (their newest 90mm macro)
- [SP 90MM F/2.8 Di 1:1 Macro](http://www.tamron-usa.com/lenses/prod/90mm.php#ad-image-0) (the older 90mm macro)
- [SP 180MM F/3.5 Di 1:1 Macro](http://www.tamron-usa.com/lenses/prod/180mm.php#ad-image-0)

The following 1:1 lens is designated Di II (for APS-C bodies):

- [SP 60MM F/2.0 Di II 1:1 Macro](http://www.tamron-usa.com/lenses/prod/60mm.php#ad-image-0)

---

[Sigma's macro lineup](https://www.sigmaphoto.com/lenses/macro-lenses) has three prime lenses that offer 1:1 with built-in motor (all are DG, i.e., full-frame):

- [105mm F2.8 EX DG OS HSM Macro](https://www.sigmaphoto.com/lenses/macro-lenses/105mm-f28-ex-dg-os-hsm-macro)
- [150mm F2.8 EX DG OS HSM APO Macro](https://www.sigmaphoto.com/lenses/macro-lenses/150mm-f2-8-ex-dg-os-hsm-apo-macro)
- [APO Macro 180mm F2.8 EX DG OS HSM](https://www.sigmaphoto.com/lenses/macro-lenses/apo-macro-180mm-f28-ex-dg-os-hsm)

---

Rokinon / Samyang only has a manual focus 100mm ƒ/2.8 lens that came out in 2015.

Comment: There's also the SP 90MM F/2.8 Di VC USD 
1:1 Macro (F004). The official name of model F017 when it was first released was also "Tamron SP 90mm f/2.8 Di VC USD Macro" and was only later changed on Tamron's web site. Some vendors still list it as "Tamron SP 90mm f/2.8 Di VC USD 1:1 Macro"

Comment: @MichaelClark damn. Tamron's naming scheme absolutely sucks. Just from the names alone, can you identify these lenses: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/compare/Tamron_F017_vs_Tamron_F272_vs_Tamron_F004/BHitems/1233542-REG_330643-USA_892886-REG

Comment: @MichaelClark it looks like the Tamron F004 is completely discontinued (it looks like the F017 replaced it), the but the even-older F272 is still available.

Comment: Yeah. It seems when they renamed the F017 they also renamed the F004 to match it as well!